# Can't reference my Entity Model for Sql-to-Linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity

I've made an entity model in a folder called "Entity" that contains my only entitymodel.

*project.Entity.ListModel.edmx*

Within my main program.cs, I'm trying to call upon it to navigate some of the tables:

```
var query = ListModel.TableName.Where(x => x.name..
```

But it keeps saying ListModel does not exist in current context.
I've even tried the full path like: *project.Entity.ListModel.TableName.Where.....*
But no luck.

This seems like a simple fix, though I'm not well aquainted with Entity Frameworks or Linq for that matter.

Any guidence would be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: The edmx is a file that contains the mapping (model) between the c# classes and the database.   When you change the database tables/fields you must refresh the mapping.  You should not be using a table name in c#.  You should be using the class created in c#.  The mapping between the class and the database is inside the edmx model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I had not initialised entity class properly.
Did that and was able to get it sorted.

```
Entity context = new Entity();
```